# Bandwidth Monitoring for Linksys E4200

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, bandwidth

I have a Linksys E4200 router with about 10 computers connecting to it. I'm looking for a way to monitor bandwidth usage in real time. I am willing to install custom firmware if it can get the job done. It seems bandwidth is leaking from the network but I suspect there are one or more users using more than their fair share and I'd like to find out exactly where it is going.

Comment: Try DD-WRT, OpenWRT, or Tomato; they all have better bandwidth logging, monitoring, and control than the stock firmware and all seem to support the E4200.

Comment: I've been looking into Tomato but I'm not sure if it offers bandwidth monitoring for individual clients or just general bandwidth usage over the whole network. I'm also having trouble finding up to date info on which version of the firmware is best with the E4200.

Comment: You might have to trawl through the forums. I spent quite a while figuring out how best to install DD-WRT on an E1000, and it ended up dying after a month just like lots of people said theirs did. Now I’m looking for a CA-42 cable to un-brick it. `:-(`

Answer (score 2):

I have recently install Tomato on my E4200, version 1.28 by Shibby, you should definitely look at that, seems to run well.

http://tomato.groov.pl/?page_id=164

What you want are  K26RT-N, which supports 5Ghz as well.

Here's an even more direct link to latest (Build '101')

http://tomato.groov.pl/download/K26RT-N/build5x-101-EN/Linksys%20E4200/

You can get the AIO build, which gives you everything. I can pretty much guarantee it will meet your needs.

EDIT: I think these are for the V1 version of the router, not sure about the newer V2's.

Answer (score 1):

You can download AdvancedTomato for E4200v1 from:

https://advancedtomato.com/downloads/router/e4200v1

Its essentially Shibby's mod with a more modern UI.

Couple of things:

1. You'll need to assign static IPs to all your clients.
2. IP traffic and Bandwidth monitoring are kept separate. You can enable one and not the other.
3. Its best to store your bandwidth logs and syslog on an external USB. You can define this under Custom Log File Path.
4. Keep in mind that enabling QoS will disable hardware acceleration.